# What is the difference between the flutter location plugin and flutter geolocator plugin

Tags: flutter

I have to design an app which would track the location of the user when that app is in use, but I am confused whether I should use location plugin or geolocator plugin as I am not understanding  the difference in their roles, could someone explain it, I am unable to get it.

Answer (score 13):

Both seem to have the same functionality.

But I would stick to geolocator because:

- more actively developed (last commit on flutterlocation is 4 months ago)
- uses `FusedLocationProviderClient`, and `LocationManager` if not available
- is supported by a company instead of a single maintainer

I hope it helps

Comment: I'd second this, I've had more success and less issues with geolocator.

Answer (score 3):

Licensing difference might be worth taking into account. Location plugin uses the 3-clause BSD licence while Geolocator uses MIT license.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer but at least in Android, location with `FusedLocationProviderClient` , works a lot better than `geolocator` in real use cases, sometimes `geolocator` takes too much time to get the position, and we have tried with medium, high accuracy, with multiple attempts every 5 seconds. `FusedLocationProviderClient` , works better because it also uses anthena triangulation and other ways to get the geolocation faster.